# Unecessary edits to my question

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala) has edited [my question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89916/changing-the-logic-for-an-exposed-taxonomy-select-in-a-view/) with a bunch of borderline unecessary edits. Some points:

- Edited to adopt American spelling
- Edited to broken english: "extend the behavior of the filter like the following", "if so, which hook I have to use?, any ideas how I might approach it?"
- Generally changing the tone I adopted

I guess I don't have a particular question as such, but am unhappy with this overzealous and in places incorrect modification of my post. Is this appropriate behaviour, or is the user trying to game the system to get more points?

Comment: I agree with you here. Some formatting changes was bad, too - especially using quotes for non-quote content. Rollback + comment is the way to go, and if edit like that happens again, you can flag for moderator's attention. But as far as I can see you already got moderator's attention there, so no need to flag this one.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/951

Comment: your question got negative vote, that's why I tried to improve your post and also I only upvoted your question.

Comment: @Bala I agree it's not the best question ever, but problem is not really in use of British English or in formatting (it's pretty decent). Anyway, it attracted some interesting answers and that's what counts! :D

Comment: What's wrong with the question? I would suggest @Bala that you don't try to make grammatical changes and changes of tone if you don't speak fluent English.

Comment: there is something wrong with your question,that's why you got one negative vote, and also as mentioned by @Molot. probably Clive will handle this and I don't want to argue anymore, if anything hurts you sorry for that.

Comment: Your question hardly shows any attempt to solve problem on your own before asking. Also, it does not explain why do you have "both" as separate term instead of truly applying both terms. And I don't see @Bala being even remotely rude here. He made what I consider to be mistake, but I can't find any bad intentions or harsh words on his side of this issue. And moderators already have spoken, so there hardly is a need for any more "suggestions".

Comment: I wasn't aware I hadn't provided enough information, and indeed nobody asked for further clarification. The problem seems very clear to me, as evidenced by the helpful reply. Could you please point me to the FAQ or question guidelines so I can better write my questions in future.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - first point. Note, that downvote is not from me. But I understand where it might came from.

Comment: @njp There's also the [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) which is pretty useful.

Answer (score 5):

I'm inclined to agree - in this case the edits were unnecessary, and didn't help to clarify or fix anything grammatical in the question. People converting English to American-English spelling is an annoyance of mine too. Both kinds are absolutely fine here, and it's accepted that questions shouldn't be edited to change spelling from one to the other.

I've rolled the edit back for now.

On the flip side, I'm totally confident this edit was made in good faith, certainly not an attempt to game the system in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I apologise for that accusation about gaming the system. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem - the user in question is a regular who is good enough to help out a lot with editing/flagging, that's why I'm sure there's nothing untoward going on here

Comment: clive thanks, i think this editor is designed to american english, editor also highlited that word as mistake.

Comment: @Bala That's probably the settings on your local machine (American English dictionary). There's no right or wrong with the spelling, it's just unnecessary to change it in this case as it implies one or the other is wrong, which it isn't (thanks to MPD's linked post for that phrasing). Please don't let this stop you editing, it's greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

In short, the user is not trying to game the system to get more points, since that user is not getting any point for editing posts written by other users.

In this case, the edit was not 100% correct, and it has been already reversed by a moderator. Reversing to a previous revision doesn't require a moderator, though: The user who asked the question can always reverse a wrong edit.

The important is not getting into edit wars; if you see the other user reversing the edit after you reverted it, flag the question (or the answer) for moderation attention.